# Converting Char to ASCII

Tags: sql

Character field in a table is having number values from 1 to 100. What would be the query to display it in order?

Comment: which database ??? what you tried ??? can you elaborate ....

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Can you add more detail to what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean character field has value 1 to 100? like a varchar column with "100" (three characters)?

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CAST(field_name AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177545.aspx)

```
ASCII ( Char_expression)
```